# Determine why an event handler disappears on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events

(In Chrome) Is there a simple way to determine when an event handler (for click) is removed from an element?  An event handler of mine is mysteriously disappearing, but I'm not sure if there's a quick and easy way to either pause or get a stack trace/exception when that occurs.

Comment: My answer assumes the event handler is removed, but your symptom may also happen if your element is destroyed; are you sure that this is not happening? (Big offenders are _innerHTML_ on an ancestor or nodes being re-built rather than modified)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your debug environment, run this code and look at your `console`.

```
(function () {
    var ael = Node.prototype.addEventListener,
        rel = Node.prototype.removeEventListener;
    Node.prototype.addEventListener = function (a, b, c) {
        console.log('Listener', 'added', this, a, b, c);
        ael.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    Node.prototype.removeEventListener = function (a, b, c) {
        console.log('Listener', 'removed', this, a, b, c);
        rel.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

If it is necessary to see more information, you may also want to call `console.trace` or give the *functions* a name so you can use [`.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) (`arguments.callee` is depreciated, hence using a name to get reference to self)